# AWS SimpleWorkflow Request Entity Too Large

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have a workflow that contains a bunch of activities. I store each activity's response in a S3 bucket. 
I pass the S3 key as an input to each activity. Inside the activity, I have a method that retrieve the data from S3 and perform some operation. But my last activity failed and threw error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Request entity too large (Service: AmazonSimpleWorkflow; Status Code: 413; Error Code: Request entity too large; Request ID: null)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:820)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:439)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:245)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.invoke(AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.java:3173)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.respondActivityTaskFailed(AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.java:2878)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.respondActivityTaskFailed(SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.java:255)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.respondActivityTaskFailedWithRetry(SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.java:246)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.execute(SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.java:208)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.ActivityTaskPoller$1.run(ActivityTaskPoller.java:97)
... 3 more
```

I know AWS SWF has some limits on data size, but I am only passing a S3 Key to activity. Inside activity, it will read from S3 and process the data. I am not sure why I am getting this error. If anyone knows, please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How long (in bytes) is the S3 object key?  That seems an unlikely suspect, but it's a question worth asking.

Comment: Thanks! Good question. The key is 74 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity failed as *respondActivityTaskFailed* SWF API call is seen in the stack trace. So my guess is that the exception message + stack trace exceeded the maximum size allowed by SWF service.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Exception message is huge. Delete it got rid of the error.